# Notification balloon every two seconds

Tags: windows

Here is the problem, I can't put it in simpler terms than the ballon on tray icon keeps popping up.

[image]

It pops up every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... Maybe following the instructions and running chkdsk would be a good place to start?

Not trying to be rude, but if I were to see a corruption message I would take it seriously and not try to ignore it!